# what's the difference between flutter_reactive_ble and flutter_blue_plus

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

what's the difference between flutter_reactive_ble and flutter_blue_plus ?

What's the difference between flutter_reactive_ble and flutter_blue_plus? I have a device that I want to connect to my Flutter application. My question is, when should I use flutter_reactive_ble and when should I use flutter_blue_plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short and simple, choose **flutter_reactive_ble** if you need advanced control and flexibility, while **flutter_blue_plus** may be a better fit for simpler use cases and ease of integration. Evaluate your project requirements, consider your familiarity with reactive programming and Bluetooth development, and choose the package that aligns best with your needs.